# How to send a key event to a QWebElement?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt5, keyevent

Give a [`QWebElement`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebelement.html), how can I send a key event? similar to this (in `QWebWidget`):

```
QKeyEvent keyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
myQWebView->event(&keyEvent);
```

I need to send a enter key to a HTML input type=textbox inside my QWebView.

Answer (score 0):

[Catch](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_catch_enter_key) your key event in your main widget. 
Then run js function using your `QWebView`

```
myQWebView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript( "js_enter_event()" );
```

Comment: this doesn't raise the event as enter key do

Comment: Did you try to  `installEventFilter` for your `QWebView` ?